# How to replace my sub directory of git to root directory of git

Tags: git

This image is my git project:

[image: This image is my git project.]

I have two projects, Android and IOS in my git repo.
However I don't need IOS project any longer.

So I want my android project to be root directory of git with previous commit logs to a new repository.

I tried to copy android project folder to a new directory and copy .git folder of previous project to it but after pushing it to a new repository, it doesn't work.
The IOS folder still posted.

Are there any other ways that you know?
What should I do?

Please give me a help.

Comment: Do you want old commits to preserve the Android logs until today, or do you want to create a modified repository that _only_ has iOS logs?

Comment: @grawity I want to create a modified repository that only has Android logs.

Answer (score 0):

Using image is not encouraged in the community because it couldn't be searched and viewed easily,  try to do this

```
project/
├── project/
│   ├── .git
│   ├── android 
│   ├── ios
```

1. git doesn't track anything outside the root directly, simplified our structure to this first

```
project/
├── .git
├── android 
├── ios
```

2. Don't move any .git directory yourself. It is meaningless. It contains all of the previous ios directory information.

=============================================================================

## Choice a   (use the original repo, remove the ios directory, update the directory )

#### 3. Let's assume you delete the ios folder or move it to somewhere else

```
project/
├── .git
├── android
```

#### 4. the ios directory is still tracked in the remote,  to stage the change,

```
git add . 
git commit -m "removed the whole ios folder"
git push
```

=============================================================================

## Choice b,   use another repo, keep the ios directory in the original position, move your android directory to somewhere else ( not recommended, your history of commit of android all gone)

in the directory containing the android directory,

```
git init 

git add .

git commit -m "first commit"

git remote add origin <your url of repo>
git push -u origin master
```